# How do I update my JRE?

Tags: java, linux, fedora

I want to update my `jre` to version `7`. What is the command for it in linux ?

Right now, on executing `java -version` it shows :

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.6) (fedora-71.1.11.6.fc16-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
update-alternatives --config java
```

For more information see the Fedora Wiki entries on [Java](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Java) and [Java FAQ](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Java/FAQ).

Comment: I installed with a success message but the command gives the same result as above

Comment: shall i re install after this edit?

Comment: @saplingPro That should take effect immediately once you select the 1.7.0 version.